# C++ make first element last element in vector while iterating

Tags: c++, c++11

When the first element of my vector meets a certain condition (the first element will always be the first one to meet the condition), I want to move it to the back of the vector. I also need this to happen while I'm iterating over my vector. Here's my code so far, it's breaking on the insert

```
for (vector< map<string, int> >::iterator iter1 = v.begin(); iter1 != v.end(); iter1++)
{
    for (map<string,int>::iterator iter2 = iter1->begin(); iter2 != iter1->end(); iter2++)
    {
        if (iter2 == iter1->begin() && (condition met))
        {
            auto x = *iter2;
            iter2 = iter1->erase(iter2);
            iter1->insert(iter1->end(), x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to preserve the order of the rest of your vector, or can you simply swap `front()` with `back()`?

Comment: I want to preserve the order of my vector. So {1,2,3,4,5} becomes {2,3,4,5,1}

Comment: Sounds like a job for std::rotate.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with either of those. How would I use it?

Comment: Your code as posted has UB; `erase` invalidates all iterators after the erased element.  `insert` can also invalidate iterators if it causes the vector to resize.

Comment: @hnefatl no because it breaks my code

Comment: @Kat Have you considered using [std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)? It sorts your container in such a way that elements that match a predicate come before the element's that don't. The relative order of the elements in each group is preserved.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no I've never heard of it before. But  this is all sort of new to me. Can you show me how it would work with my problem?

Comment: @0x5453 I don't know what UB is. If that all invalidates my vector, then solve do I solve this problem?

Comment: UB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: @Kat UB = Undefined Behavior.  Basically your program is broken and probably will not behave as you expect.  (Usually UB causes your program to crash, but not always.)  `std::rotate` looks perfect for this.  `std::rotate(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin()), v.end());`

Comment: @0x5453 It would be extremely helpful if you could just show me how that would work with my code.

Comment: @Kat The supplied link contains example already. Please take a moment to read the documentation everyone is referring you to.

Comment: Is it the elements of the vector that you want to be rotated or is it the elements of the maps within the vector?

Comment: @FrancisCugler It is the elements of the vector that I want to alter.

Comment: @Kat Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Why not use a deque?